# 2D drawing file to Monochrome in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, monochrome

I want to change the color DWG to monochrome in the Forge viewer. Is there any option to change it to monochrome?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the method setGrayscale to switch to black and white

viewer.setGrayscale(true)

The other method setSwapBlackAndWhite could swap the background and front color

Comment: I appreciate your answer. viewer.setGrayscale(true) achieve the monochrome facility in Forge viewer.

Comment: Is there any facility to export/download the monochromatic file to PDF?

Comment: no such API with APS Viewer, but you could take advantage of 3rd party library such as jsPDF. Please check this blog https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/generate-pdf-report-forge-viewer